# Jquery doesn't remove class when holding backspace

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that uses Ajax to get search results in real time, as the user types. It has a check if the input field's length is 1 or more, and if it is then it adds the class 'open' to display the dropdown for the search results. It also has an else statement, where if the length is 0 it removes open. This works fine on my localhost, but on my website if i hold backspace on more than two characters, it won't remove open (If i tap backspace it always works).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").on('input', function() {
    if ($('#search').val().length >= 1) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/url",
        data: {
          "json_str": $('#search').val()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          if (!$("#searchbar").hasClass("open")) {
            $("#searchbar").addClass("open")
          }
          if (data.length == undefined) {
            $('#display').html("No results")
          } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              console.log(data[i].username)
              $('#display').append("<some html>")
            }
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#searchbar").removeClass("open")
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Try binding the 'change' event instead

Comment: Your design is flawed with fast typers, you will be sending out tons of requests. You need to look at throttling.

Comment: @epascarello Thank you, I found an article on throttling that fixed my problem. My code now aborts the last AJAX call if it hasn't been completed when a new request is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution, I am now aborting the last AJAX call if a new one is made before a response comes in.

```
var request = null;
$("#search").on('input', function() {
  if (request){
    request.abort()
}
if ($('#search').val().trim().length >= 1) {
  request = $.ajax({.........
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to trim the input value

```
if($('#search').val().trim().length)
```